# Golang: fmt, variadic args and %!(EXTRA type=value) error

Tags: go

I'm implementing a wrapper around the standard log package to make a logger with various log levels.

I have the following interface:

```
type Logger interface {
  Trace(fmt string, args ...interface{})
  Debug(fmt string, args ...interface{})
  Info(fmt string, args ...interface{})
  Warn(fmt string, args ...interface{})
  Error(fmt string, args ...interface{})
  Fatal(fmt string, args ...interface{})
  Panic(fmt string, args ...interface{})
}
```

In the implementation I have something like this (not the exact code)

```
func Info(format string, args ...interface{}){
  msg := fmt.Sprintf(format, args...)
  log.Println(msg)
}
```

Now, assume I call my library like this:

```
logger.Info("Hello %s", "World")
```

I get the printout: "Hello %!(EXTRA string=WORLD)", instead of the expected "Hello World". There a similar output if I do

```
msg := fmt.Sprintf(format, args)
```

This returns "Hello World%!EXTRA []interface{}=[]".

Comment: your format string argument is called `fmt`, but you're using `format` in the `Sprintf` call.

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate what you're describing: http://play.golang.org/p/IKwT8oKX3k

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't reproduce this behavior. Are you sure it's not a simple error that you forgot to show here?

https://play.golang.org/p/-jtmll17Xj

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Info(format string, args ...interface{}){
    msg := fmt.Sprintf(format, args...)
    fmt.Print(msg)
}

func main() {
    Info("Hello %s", "World")
}
```

Prints

```
Hello World
```

According to [the `fmt` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/), `%!(EXTRA string=WORLD)` is added to the string when you pass extra parameters, unexpected by the format. Maybe you are using the format string `"Hello World"` instead of `"Hello %s"`, or passing the argument twice?

Comment: The error was indeed between chair and keyboard. I mixed up the following interfaces:

    `func Print(v ...interface{})' and 
    'func Printf(format string, v ...interface{})`

Some of my code was calling the library without a format string. See here for a more detailed example: [link](http://play.golang.org/p/Xx79qujaFp)

Comment: @BoppreH That *fmt* doc reference was invaluable.

Answer (score 10):

The error was between the chair and keyboard. I mixed up the following interfaces:

```
func Print(v ...interface{})
func Printf(format string, v ...interface{})
```

Some of my code was calling the library without a format string.See here for a more detailed example: http://play.golang.org/p/Xx79qujaFp

Answer (score 0):

Happens aswell when your message has no verbs and the varargs are empty but coming from elsewhere:

```
func CustomPrintf(message string, a ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf(message, a) // for no verbs in message you'll get this "EXTRA" suffix
}
```

That's a special case of a general error. You've got to spread `a` first. So use `fmt.Printf(message, a...)` to make it to varags again.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you pass nil params to your format, for instance:

```
myStr := fmt.Sprintf("check/%s", "hello", nil)
```

will set the value of myStr to: "check/hello%!"
In this example the extra params was the third param with nil value.

so make sure to remove any extra params.

Answer (score 0):

Also, happens due to a simple (typo?) if you forget/miss putting in the "%".
e.g.

```
fmt.Printf("v\n", myvar)
```

instead of

```
fmt.Printf("%v\n", myvar)
```

obviously not a "syntax" error, so nothing for the compiler to catch.
I realize this nets out to the same as some of the other answers, but I think this is clearer and (maybe?) the most common cause.